# Programmatically setting CheckBoxList items using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, checkbox

I've created an ASP CheckBoxList and my goal is to have the first 3 options selected by default.  Any number of the first 3 options can be selected together, but the 4th option is mutually exclusive.  So I created a method to see if the 4th option is checked, then deselect the first 3 options.  Also, if any of the first 3 selections is checked, then deselect the 4th option.  This works fine, until I add in jQuery UI for the CSS.  Now it won't uncheck any of the other options on the click event.  I checked and it is going into the method.  There are no errors.  It's just not unchecking the checkboxes.  Also, sometimes I have to click the checkbox twice for it to select/deselect the options.  Any ideas?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="StatusCheckBoxList" CssClass="jqcheck">
      <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>


function ChangeOptions(chkid) {

        var op1 = document.getElementById(chkid + "_0");
        var op2 = document.getElementById(chkid + "_1");
        var op3 = document.getElementById(chkid + "_2");
        var op4 = document.getElementById(chkid + "_3");

        if (op4.checked) {
            op1.checked = false;
            op2.checked = false;
            op3.checked = false;
        } 
        else {
            op4.checked = false;
        }
    }
```

And in the code behind, I'm attaching the onclick event:

```
StatusCheckBoxList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeOptions('" + StatusCheckBoxList.ClientID + "')");
```

CSS Markup:

```
function loadJqueryUI() {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".jqcheck").buttonset();
}
```

This is the jQuery UI I'm feature I'm trying to use: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Comment: Post the resulting HTML code. If you're using Chrome, press F12, use the magnifying glass to point at your elements, then paste the structure.

What is possibly happening is that the LIstItem's elements are not being parsed with the ID you specified.

Comment: This is a dumbed down version of my code.  I can't actually paste the html markup of my real code.  Are you suggesting that jQuery is changing the name of the listitem elements?  This code works just fine if I remove the CssClass="jqcheck" part of the code.

Comment: Not jQuery, but ASP.NET instead. To parse the  `<asp:` markup elements, ASP.NET changes the ID so they are unique under (eventual) master pages. The ListItems's ID are probably being changed during runtime.

Comment: Try to set the ID and the `ClientIDMode = "static"` attributes for each ListItem.

Comment: Can you Post the CSS markup for jqcheck?

Comment: If I add an alert such as alert(op1.checked) then I am getting the correct response such as true or false, so the markup is fine and it's finding the elements.  It's just not able to set them for some reason.  It has something to do with jQuery UI.  The link to jQuery UI is here: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox  The only style I put in was: $(".jqcheck").buttonset();

Comment: Check to see if any other jquery plugins that you use in the page conflicts with jquery or change the order (precedence) of js files to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  The jquery object needed to refresh, so adding the following code at the end of ChangeOptions() function fixed the issue:

```
$(".jqcheck").buttonset("refresh");
```